# Can a DC-DC regulator support a high inductive load?

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter, inductor, inductance, coil

Can a cheap voltage regulator ([DC to DC Buck Converter Step Down](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00HV4EPG8)) blow up when I connect/disconnect a pretty big inductor (about 9000 turns) or is it self-protected?

I am asking because it makes a pretty big flame when I connect the inductor to the power supply (15V).

Comment: If the seller can't answer that or provide proper data which answers that ... buy from one who can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be on the safe side, you should add a flyback diode parallel to the electromagnet.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode

Make sure you use a diode rated for (more than) the maximum current that will flow through the inductor.

The maximum current, in Amperes, used by that inductor will be 15V/R where R is the series resistance.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage regulator u talk about has short circuit protection. Usually inductors are fed alternative not continuous voltage. What are you trying to do?

Comment: "What are you trying to do?" - a magnet :)

Comment: They have short-circuit protection indeed but I probably need anti-reverse polarity protection :)

Comment: For a magnet you have to compute the current you need and get a proper power supply. The anti-reverse polarity can be solved with a diode if needed.